# Openshot 2.2 uses all my cpu and freezes

Tags: cpu, openshot

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I just installed Openshot 2.2. When I load a video, and begin to preview it, Openshot begins to use over 50% of my cpu and after about 5 seconds freezes.  Any ideas or fixes for this?

Thanks

Comment: What are your hardware specifications ? And especially, how much RAM do you have ?

Comment: 0/0                               memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4/8                             memory      32KiB L1 cache
/0/4/9                             memory      1MiB L2 cache
/0/7                               memory      24KiB L1 cache
/0/26                              memory      4GiB System Memory
/0/26/0                            memory      4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333
/0/26/1                            memory      SODIMM [empty]

Comment: Sorry, that came out a bit ugly, believe it is 4 GiB

Comment: What about swap space ?

Comment: robert@robert-Lenovo-C260:~$ sudo swapon --show
[sudo] password for robert: 
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-1 partition 3,9G 1,5M   -1

Comment: My guess is that you are running out of memory and swapspace. Try to run 'top' in a terminal, and monitor memory and swap usage when loading and previewing the video.

Comment: Thanks Soren, added more swapspace, but still slow, I think problem is with Openshot.

Comment: I will add it as an answer ..

Answer (score 0):

Video editing is a very memory intensive operation, so you are probably running short of memory and swap space. Try running `top` while loading and previewing the video.

Adding more swap will make the system run better, at least for some time. But heavy paging / swapping to disk generates a high load on your disk (the same disk as you are reading the video from) so a better solution would be to add more memory.